# Problem with Seurat reference mapping

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, sequence-annotation, 10x-genomics, cellranger

I have `10X scRNA-seq multiome's 3' poly-A capture (scRNA-seq+ATAC-seq)` from PBMC

Using Seuratreference mapping, I mapped my scRNA-seq part on reference PBMC (for cell type annotation)

I have also tried Seurat zimuth shiny app

But likely just a few of my cells has been mapped on the reference

Please look at this

[image]

Do you think this because my data is multiome or something else is going wrong?

Please any body has some experience help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Multiome seems to have cells with much higher mitochondrial gene content. I don't understand the biology behind this. But in using a cut off of 5% (i.e. remove cells with >5% MT genes) I lose over 80% of cells in multiome data. Also, here is the Signac tutorial where they use a 20% cut off for multiome data - https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/weighted_nearest_neighbor_analysis.html ("WNN analysis of 10x Multiome, RNA + ATAC")

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in [my](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/17513/73) [answers](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/16448/73) to similar questions, there are a lot of cells with very high mitochondrial gene content. It would be a good idea to work out why that is before doing any more downstream processing.

These cells will, of course, be filtered out by the thresholds you have set.